# Professor not teaching

Tags: united-states, teaching, university

I have a professor who is teaching two-credit medical terminology course. This course is being taught at a public university in Montana.

She taught the first class session we had with her, and now just sits in the back of the class room “filling out work notes from being a PT,” and is now having the students who are taking course teach the rest of the material for the semester.

**My question is, is this okay and legal?** I am paying to be taught by the expert in the field, “the professor,” not a student trying to learn the material. I am not also happy with forking my hard-earned money to have the professor do nothing but fill out patient notes during class time.

Comment: Go to the [provost](https://www.montana.edu/provost/students/complaints.html).

Comment: Hi B406, sorry you're having that problem. I edited your question a little to make it more readable. I also assume you meant a medical "terminology" course, and not a "terminally" one.

Answer (score 9):

Having students explain material to each other is a perfectly normal and reasonable pedagogical technique. "Teaching a class" is not synonymous with "giving a lecture".

It's not clear to me from your description whether your instructor is using a method like this (if so, I'd expect them to be monitoring and providing feedback, even if they aren't lecturing) but you do not recognize this as an appropriate way to teach/it is not your preference, or whether they are actually *not teaching*.

If they are actually *not teaching* and spending the instruction time completing other tasks, then as a commenter suggests there will be avenues in your institution for managing complaints, and you can file one. It's likely to be helpful if multiple students share your concerns. Be polite and specific in your complaint to have the best chance it will be handled seriously.

Unfortunately, it's very unlikely that you have any legal recourse besides taking your money elsewhere. If they won't make changes and you are not happy with the instruction you're receiving at a given institution, your only other option is to apply to become a student elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, this is a perfectly valid teach methodology. If she is in the room to correct errors and prevent misconceptions, the students will learn the most when it is their turn to prepare the talk.

Comment: I feel like your last paragraph is a bit condescending. Surely you know that for the vast majority of students (especially somewhere thinly populated like Montana) it is exceedingly difficult to just "pack up and go to another university" after having one bad course.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Better after the edit? My intent is to be realistic about what the options are if complaining about it doesn't solve the problem (as well as suggesting one should consider carefully what the scope of this problem is, especially if it's been mischaracterized here).

Comment: I mean, I guess?

Answer (score 3):

The real question is how much you are learning this way. The only thing that matters in the end is not how much time a professor spent at the blackboard herself but whether *reasonably hard working students who diligently do all assignments* (the rest do not count and have no real say in the matter) master the subject. If yes, I do not see what is there to complain about. You are paying for an opportunity to learn, not for a show in some particular format, and if it is there, all contract obligations are met IMHO. If no, then yeah, there is something to be corrected, indeed, and you may have a good reason for bring this issue up though I would start with bringing it up with the professor herself. Just try to be constructive then and start your sentence with "I believe I would learn more if ...". Go higher only if you meet total lack of understanding at this level and if you meet the above criteria in italic (if you don't meet them, look in the mirror first and correct all problems there before accusing anyone else of anything).

By itself, the technique of letting students make a class presentation on a regular basis is actually a good idea and I use it a lot myself, especially in graduate courses, though I prefer not to switch to that format entirely. I normally use 2:1 ratio (for every two hours I'm talking, I have 1 hour when students are talking). But the optimal ratio may be discipline and subject specific, so I wouldn't be surprised if 0:1 were chosen by somebody under certain circumstances.

With all that said, I *do* know of some cases where professors turned their classes into some meaningless activity where students were being occupied with some tasks requiring no attention from the professor and in the end everybody got an A for just being there, which, IMHO, only aggravated the problem. So it is really impossible to tell much about your particular situation without knowing more details.

Answer (score 3):

**It’s almost certainly not okay**. Teaching is part of a professor’s job and a significant justification for the salary that they receive. Now, it is true that there are contexts when “teaching” is not synonymous with “lecturing”, as another answer points out. However, that fact is not as relevant as the other answer makes it out to be, for two reasons:

1. Those contexts are fairly limited. In a generic undergraduate class at a generic university, it will be assumed  and expected that a professor will spend a significant proportion of her classroom time actually lecturing, barring very specific reasons why a different mode of delivering instruction is justified and makes more sense.
2. More importantly, the *absolute bare minimum* that will be expected of any professor in the US is that during class time, they are *actually doing something related to the class*. Being physically or mentally absent from the classroom for extended periods of time, and particularly working on other things like answering emails or writing up notes that are unrelated to the class, would not be acceptable behaviors for a professor at my university, nor, I’d be willing to bet, at OP’s university or any self-respecting institution.

To emphasize the last point, even in a setting where a professor is implementing some system where students explain the material to each other, a conscientious professor would still listen in on the discussion and be on standby to correct inaccuracies, point out important points the presenter has failed to mention, make clarifying remarks that push the discussion along, etc. Basically the professor is still running the class and is still in charge. To be working on unrelated things and letting students run the show without even paying attention to what’s going on seems to me like a clear dereliction of duty. So no, it is not okay.